# Fixing Path_traversel when downloading a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, path-traversal

How to fix this code so that it does not accuse this type of vulnerability?

I'm using checkmarx to scan, and he encountered this problem when downloading a file

Error reported by checkmarx:

> Method Index at line 13 of
> src\BR.Rve.UI.Site\Controllers\DownloadFileController.cs gets dynamic
> data from the fileName element. This element’s value then flows
> through the code and is eventually used in a file path for local disk
> access in Index at line 13 of
> src\BR.Rve.UI.Site\Controllers\DownloadFileController.cs. This may
> cause a Path Traversal vulnerability." and I'm having a little trouble
> solving this

and I'm having a little trouble solving this

My original code:

```
     public FileResult Index(string fileName)
        {
            string rootPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FinalUploadFolder");
            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(string.Format("{0}/{1}", rootPath,fileName));            
            return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
        }
```

I've tried this solution below, but it didn't work

```
      private static readonly char[] InvalidFilenameChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
      public ActionResult Index(string fileName)
        {
            if (fileName.IndexOfAny(InvalidFilenameChars) >= 0)
                  return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

            string rootPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FinalUploadFolder");
            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(rootPath,fileName))));            
            return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
        }
```

What could I do in the code to avoid this type of problem when scanning

Comment: So what is the problem ? I'm not sure I am understanding the question

Comment: @TheGeneral Thats the error the checkMarx is point: 
"Method Index at line 13 of src\BR.Rve.UI.Site\Controllers\DownloadFileController.cs gets dynamic data from the fileName element. This element’s value then flows through the code and is eventually used in a file path for local disk access in Index at line 13 of src\BR.Rve.UI.Site\Controllers\DownloadFileController.cs. This may cause a Path Traversal vulnerability." and I'm having a little trouble solving this

Comment: After you do `Path.Combine(...)` - you need to check if resulting path is subdirectory of `rootPath`. And most importantly - the user under which your web service runs should not have access to any directories it doesn't need. Then even if you miss such path traversal - OS will deny access anyway.

Comment: @Evk Got it ... would you have an example to help me, because what I tried didn't work

Comment: Here is a sample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61707298/5311735